# Implement responsive Master/Detail in UWP using only one page

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, master-detail

I would like to know if there's a way to implement a responsive Master/Detail page using only one. What I want is something exactly like the Project here:

https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlMasterDetail

Except for the detail that instead of using two pages and navigating from one to another I would only use one page.

Is there a way to do it? If so, could you link me a working example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Except for the detail that instead of using two pages and navigating from one to another I would only use one page.

After going through [the project](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlMasterDetail), I found it implemented a responsive master/detail experience **based on the size of the screen**. When the app view is sufficiently **wide**, the master list and detail view should appear side by side **in the same app page**. However, on smaller screen sizes, the two pieces of UI should appear on different pages, allowing the user to navigate between them. From my point of view, I think this is a good solution for implementing a responsive master/detail experience.

> Is there a way to do it? If so, could you link me a working example?

[The project](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlMasterDetail) already shows how to implement responsive Master/Detail in UWP using only one page, but it implements more and that makes it a little complex to understand. So I make a simple example which directly shows how to implement responsive Master/Detail in UWP using only one page.

Following is the main steps:

First, create a ListView to show master information in xaml page:

```
<!--Master VIEW-->
<ListView x:Name="ItemListView" Margin="0,0,0,8">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,8,0,0">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" FontSize="25"  Width="400" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Second, specify the details view that shows the details item **related to the selection on the master list** in the same xaml page:

```
<!--DETAILS VIEW-->
<StackPanel Grid.Column="1" x:Name="ContentPanelDetail" Margin="10,0,0,0" DataContext="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=ItemListView}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" MaxHeight="80" FontSize="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Margin="0" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="DetailTextBlock" FontSize="35" Text="{Binding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,18,40,0" Width="500"  Height="Auto" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
</StackPanel>
```

Then, set the ItemsSource for the ListView in code behind:

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    //set the ItemsSource for the ListView
    ItemDetails messageData = new ItemDetails();
    ItemListView.ItemsSource = messageData.Collection;
    ItemListView.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
```

Last but not least, put Master View and Details View into a SplitView and use VisualStateManager to make it more **[responsive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/layout/screen-sizes-and-breakpoints-for-responsive-design)**.

Here is the [simple example](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=E754412D31A2DF3D!118&authkey=!AClEGhJYrdd_S7I&ithint=file%2czip) and the [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5FbbU.gif) for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

To implement Master/Detail pattern on your page, you don't have to do it yourself. Instead you can use MasterDetailsView control from [UWP Community Toolkit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/masterdetailsview), it does a lot work for you + it is well documented.

**Note:** For details section of the control, do not set background to null (NoSelectionContent will be visible).